# SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: node.js

I am using this code of node.js and i see the error at the word class

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const Market = require('./market')
const signalr = require('signalr-client')
const EventEmitter = require('events')
const cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper')

const wsURI = 'wss://socket.bittrex.com/signalr'
const reconnectWaitTime = 100 //reconnect wait time in ms
const maxCurrenciesPerClient = 20


class MarketManager extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(replayHistory) {

    super()
    this._replayHistory = replayHistory        
    this._setStartValues()
    }
```

I used strict mode in many places but the same error

Comment: you probably need to upgrade your node version

Comment: I am trying this now .. I feel it will work .. thanks for you response

Comment: It will definitely work. Newer versions support latest Ecmascript versions with out `use strict`

Comment: the new problem is that i cannot upgrade node.js .. do you know a straight forward way

Comment: which node version you're using?

Comment: i restarted my machine .. and every thing is ok after upgrading .. now i have issues in the code itself .. I am trying to solve them